# Playing an audio in the front-end without storing any cache to avoid illegal downloading

Tags: javascript, java, html, gwt, audio-streaming

I have a system that has HTML + GWT in the front-end, and a Java on the back-end. The back-end can already send WAV files currently, in its entirety, and the front-end needs to be able to play it, and not to allow any form of downloading due to security/privacy concerns. This can be achieved partly with the standard HTML5 audio tag.

The problems I'm facing are:

- I can deactivate downloading on the audio tag by adding `controlsList="nodownload"`, but that is easily circumvented by removing this tag on Developer Tools of Chrome, which will pop-up the Download button right back
- The file is cached in its entirety as soon as its played, regardless of any `preload` values I try. Then, it's just a matter of finding the right file in `C:/Users/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/ Default/Cache/Cache_data`, adding the WAV extension, and playing it

Thoughts:

- I'm thinking that maybe a streaming solution could work, where either there's no cache at all, or segmented and sequential caches (such as Netflix), which can make it hard for the user to link them all together
- I've seen an option to encrypt audio in the back-end, and decrypt on the front-end with Encrypted Media Extensions (https://web.dev/articles/eme-basics), though I'm afraid that even after all this development the cache will exist locally whenever the file is played
- I've seen that if I manage the audio playing with Javascript and using the Web Audio API (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API), it can handle streaming, though I'm not sure how the cache would work here.
- I've seen paid plugins that can do this, though I'm leaning towards a solution using open source code. But in the end if it's too much of a hassle, I would reconsider.

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: It's not possible to avoid any content you send to the client being cached/saved. The file has to be received and stored in order to be processed. Even streaming content will follow this pattern, although more steps are involved for the client to retain the data. The age old rule applies; if you don't want your content to be stolen, don't put it online.

Comment: Hi @RoryMcCrossan, thanks for the answer. Do you have any idea how the cache will work when using the Web Audio API, by sending the audio in chunks? I guess the question can be more of: how can I make the cache non intelligible, maybe segmented, or at least not as obvious as in the example I gave of changing the extension?

Comment: Be aware that if the audio plays on the user's machine, they can just press "record" on a screen recording app to capture the audio. There are plugins that allow you to use your own machine's speaker output as the input for an audio recording app.

Comment: Of course @Kokodoko, the possibilites are endless, but I would like to control at least the cache in some way. By the way, this is an internal system with specific users using it, so we are not really expecting abuse by part of the users, but we want to set some kind of minimal control

Comment: If you don't expect abuse by the users it may be enough to just use audio streaming. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Audio_and_video_delivery/Live_streaming_web_audio_and_video If you really want to be secure the only way seems to be encryption (the cached files are encrypted and only the audio player can decrypt it)

Comment: Ok. @Kokodoko Do you happen to know how the cache will behaviour when using, for instance, gstreamer in the back-end + Web Audio API on the front-end? Or some other combination. What you said about the cache being encrypted is interesting too.

Comment: I think that is how spotify and such services protect the cache files. The files are there, but only their own player can decrypt them. The player has an authentication to know for sure that the user is nicely paying for the subscription. And once you are logged in the player has the key for decrypting.

Comment: Perfect, that makes sense. I thought that encrypting would be more time consuming than streaming for the development, but in the end it might not be so. I'll focus on that for now, thanks!